# What does ($0) mean in function calls in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, function, class, intellisense

I'm using VS 2022 to learn Python. When I try to call a function with Intellisense and press , the call usually ends with a ($0) along with it. [image: Like this]

What does it mean? It gets really tiring to delete it everytime I call a function.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python and looks like a placeholder for the first parameter.

Comment: @DYZ  Ah okay. Is it specific to VS? Could I disable it somehow in options? I found a very brute method of disabling  "Options>Text Editor> Python> Advanced> Automatically add brackets for function" but it also predictably disables addition of brackets.